# How to avoid grab when using posix named semphore?

Tags: c, linux

I was troubled when using a posix named semphore in multi-processed.
After I used ***sem_wait()*** in process A, and process A is in semphore context. while process B grab cpu from process A before the sempore is released,  and process B will keep waiting for the sempohore.
I wonder if there is a mechanism such as ***priority reversal*** that can avoid the situation I mentioned in linux os.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `A` is in the critical region and you want priority inheritance from a process `B` to `A` when `B` is waiting on `A`'s lock? Note: priority reversal is the problem, inheritance is a suggested solution. On Linux, this needs [rt_mutex](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/rt-mutex.txt).

Comment: A and B are two daemon process, they have same priority.

Comment: Then your problem statement does not make sense to me ...

Comment: Hey, dhe, thanks a lot. I think I have solved the problem. In my opinion, the posix semphore is actually an atomic operation, bug I made a mistake in the critical region where I invoked a sleep, which results a CPU release. So another process may take the advantage of CPU.